# Remember Cell Value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello I have a table in which I want to Change the value of C1 by reducing it by the value in B1.

For Example If C1 is 10, and I enter 3 in B1, the new value of C1 is 7. But now if I edit the number in B1 to 2 it subtracts 2 from 7 and not 10, and the new value of C1 is 5.

Any way to do this ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are the changes based on math? Excel cells can only store a single value, so if you want to always compare to a value other than the one in the cell, you'll need a third cell to do the reference work. Also, what are you actually trying to accomplish? This sort of question sounds like it may be a homework problem that you're trying to solve. Is that correct?

Comment: You need VBA for that. Formulas define the value in a cell, and can change it if a value it references elsewhere changes. But it can only do that in the cell with the formula, it can't stick a value into a different cell. So say A1 contains 10. C1 could contain the formula `=A1-B1`.  If you put 3 into B1, C1 will show 7. If you change B1 to 2, C1 will show 8 because the formula hasn't changed. Cells don't remember what they used to contain, and it is a problem to create a cell or chain of cells with circular references (directly or indirectly, a cell is affected by its own value). (cont'd)

Comment: Nor can a cell store a previous result on its own.  If C1 used to be 10 and the last value in B1 made its result 7, another cell can't remember the 10 or the 7 when B1 changes again; all values are based on the current state of the worksheet. Also, a cell can't contain a constant and a formula at the same time, and a formula can't change itself.  So you can't start with 10 in C1, then have it change to a formula that displays its old value minus what's in a different cell.  With VBA, you can have a change in a cell (like B1) trigger a new calculation and stick a value in C1.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of the answer fixer1234 has given, the most simple way of doing the VBA that I can imagine would be:
Right-click the sheet tab, "show code" and use the worksheet_change event to trigger the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value - Range("B1").Value
End If
End Sub
```

This is a minimal example. It's probably a good idea to add conditions to not get errors. 
Like if you enter a letter in `B1`this would result in an error, while if you used

```
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value - Range("B1").Value
```

it would just ignore it.